# convert diff file to Trac style html

Tags: svn, diff

I have a SVN repository and a Trac. Trac's diff function is excellent. However, some of the files with password are not visible to all team members and Trac cannot achive this permission control. Review Board seems not able to achieve this purpose either.

Since the permission is configured in SVN. Using svn client should be able to keep members only view code with permission. So I want to ask team member to review code by command like below:

```
svn diff -r 7396:7397
```

Raw diff text is not good enough. There is a solution the specify opendiff (we use Mac) to svn --diff-cmd. But this solution seems not able to know what the original file is. The title of the diff window is a temporary file. I need to know the filename because there are multiple files in a diff.

I think it would be great to have a command line tool diff2html to convert diff file to html file like this:

```
(svn diff -r 7396:7397 | diff2html > /tmp/svndiff.html); firefox /tmp/svndiff.html
```

I hope the result is a side by side diff like Trac screenshot below:

[image: sameple diff output style]

I have tried to Google some diff2html tools but none of them seems work. Can someone give me suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: "However, some of the files with password are not visible to all team members and Trac cannot achive this permission control." I would focus on solving this issue. Trac has a very good permissions model and it should be possible to grant permissions to even fine-grained resources.

Comment: I don't think Trac has the ability to control detail SVN permission. In Trac, there is BROWSER_VIEW to control whether user can view SVN code and commit history as well as diff. But Trac backend access SVN as super user. There is no relationship between Trac users and SVN users. So I don't think Trac can know which Trac user has permission to access SVN as some SVN user. It would be too complicate to achieve this user connection.

Comment: There certainly CAN be a relationship between Trac and SVN users, and it is not too complicated. Trac and SVN can share the same authentication store. For example, they can both use [basic authentication](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracModWSGI#UsingBasicAuthentication) or digest authentication. Further, Trac can use [SVN path-based permission](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) to control access granular access to repository resources. See [AuthzSourcePolicy](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFineGrainedPermissions#AuthzSourcePolicy).

Comment: Your are my hero! I can't believe that Trac can achieve this awesome function. Problem solved.